# ERROR Sorry! ionic serve can only be run in an Ionic project directory. (when updated visual studio code)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have updated visual studio code to 1.27.2 version and when I run my existed ionic project using ionic serve command I am getting an error like

**[ERROR] Sorry! ionic serve can only be run in an Ionic project directory.**

I am trying to resolve this problem for two days can someone help me, please

### ionic info:-

```
[WARN] You are not in an Ionic project directory. Project context may be missing.
cli packages: (C:\Users\krishna.kovilampati\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
System:
    Node : v10.0.0
    npm  : 5.6.0
    OS   : Windows 10
Misc:
    backend : pro
```

Comment: No one have idea about it?

Answer (score 1):

As per the error you are not in ionic project directory. CLick on File > Open Folder > {{Selet your project Folder}} . After that go to console Type ionic serve. If any issue is comming please do post with a screen shot. it will be helpful

Comment: i am in ionic project directory

Comment: Can you share me you path?

Comment: with screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Try this steps properly

**Ionic Framework**   [Link](https://ionicframework.com/getting-started#cli)

Comment: What is this link?,how can it usefull for me?

Comment: If you can go through this documents you don't need to face such error.